# Blender 3d NURBS Path objects move

Tags: game-engine, objects, nurbs-surface

I was trying to create train tracks using NURBS path and everything looks to be great till I press play.

As soon as I play it in Blender Game Engine, the objects are no longer merged and have a clear separation (making it unrealistic).

I believe the problem is that one of the object moves till it reaches the other ones edges, but what I want is that they should not realign themselves.

Here is the [blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gu0aui1z7esavjl/track.blend?dl=0).

Comment: Recalculate your normals `View 3D > Edit Mode > Toolbar > Shading/UVs > Recalculate Normals`

Comment: Tried Merge and recalculated the norms and nothing works

Comment: Double check and visually make sure your normals are right `View 3D > Edit Mode > Select All Faces > N-Panel > Mesh Display > Face Normals`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It finally worked! I was trying to recalculate normals of the base but I was not recalculating for the tracks which were being duplicated. So the steps are the same for all objects and related objects to the curve

View 3D > Edit Mode > Toolbar > Shading/UVs > Recalculate Normals